# PHP strtotime() vs. date.js parse()

Tags: php, javascript, datejs

I've got a website where users can potentially type in their own dates before they're sent to the server. So I obviously need to parse what they give me and get it into a standard format before actually using it. So I used PHP's [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function, which is pretty forgiving about what it will accept as input.

But I'm also using [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) on the site and its parse() function is pretty good, too. Should I use that on the user input before sending it to the server? Which one is better?

I'll keep strtotime() on the back end for safety, but if date.js is better I'll add that to the client.

(To clarify, I'm expecting mostly American date formats. But should that change, anything that eases that transition is preferred.)

Comment: If you're catering for more than one demographic, e.g. english/american think too about how you'd handle a date such as 2/4/2012 - Second April, or 4th Feb?

Comment: date.js should allow you to check the date before any form is sent to the server... might be better to use in your case.  But even better, it's not a bad idea to add some checking on the back-end with PHP for good measure.

Comment: I'll always check it on the back end to be safe. But if the parsing in date.js is better I'll add that to the front before it even gets to the server.

Comment: @Adam: ponder the horrors of `10/11/12`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you feel `strtotime()` is meeting your needs, there isn't a great reason to change it on the client side. However, `strtotime()` makes a couple of assumptions which you need to stay on top of:

[From the `strtotime()` documentation:](http://php.net/manual/function.strtotime.php)

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.

If you are allowing your client to send the date in any format they choose, the above could be a source of confusion.  I just tested the dates `5/1/12` and `5-1-12` in date.js, and both were parsed as May 1st, 2012.  PHP would interpret the two as May 1st 2012 and Jan 12th 2005(!!) respectively.

```
echo date("Y-M-n", strtotime("5/1/12"));
// 2012-May-5
echo date("Y-M-n", strtotime("5-1-12"));
// 2005-Jan-1 (whoops!)
```

However, pre-formatting the date has the obvious benefit of some insurance that the entered date is valid.  Keeping `strtotime()` on the backend also ensures that you don't need a JavaScript-enabled client to send requests. Your PHP could still be called as a web service, etc, without the client needing to be a web browser.

Comment: That's a good point about the formats. Most users will probably just click the date picker and choose there, which avoids the problem. But I want to catch as many cases as I can for those pesky few who like to type.

Answer (score 0):

Both.

You absolutely do need to validate the date in PHP, because one or more of your users may have disabled Javascript.

Javascript validation is nice because you can have a date entered in an input control, validate it in the `onblur` handler, and write the validated date back to the control. So after the user types the date of birth 2/5/01 and leaves the control, the date changes to 2 May 2001 and not only does the user knows that the date is interpreted correctly, but `strtotime()` also gets an unambiguous value.

You can also use much better validation feedback, from a UX point of view. Javascript can do the following (which is probably well known but it took a bit of searching for me to find it). Put an element in the page, like

```
<div id="DobReply"></div>;
```

Then the function which validates the Date of Birth can do

```
document.getElementById("DobReply").innerHTML = "Current age is "+age;
```

where age is a variable calculated from the entered date of birth, and today's date. As soon as the user leaves the control, the calculated age pops up, and if the user entered the current year (it happens) then she might spot the error immediately.

So I wouldn't get rid of datejs validation either. But all of this is lost if Javascript is disabled, you can get invalid dates, dates in weird formats, or anything. So if you can only have one, keep the `strtotime()`.